# Measure Not Preserving Homeomorphism

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory

Are there homeomorphisms that do not preserve measure (Let us consider Lebesgue Measure)? I ask this because, I currently cannot think one but while googling, I get Measure Preserving Homeomorphisms. So this specification is made perhaps because there are homeomorphisms that do not preserve measure?

P.S. I am fairly beginner in this topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x\mapsto x^2$ is a homeomorphism from $[0,1]$ onto $[0,1]$ that does not preserve measure. Moreover, every continuous, strictly increasing function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ that is not bounded below or above is a homeomorphism. Clearly, "most" such functions do not preserve measure.

Answer (score 0):

Any homeomorphism that isn't equal to the identity or the map $x\mapsto 1-x$ on the space $[0,1]$ with the Lebesgue measure will not preserve measure I think.

Comment: Does anyone know if we can drop the 'a.e' condition, given that we're considering homeomorphisms?

Comment: Sure, two continuous functions are the same if they are equal a.e.: If $f$ and $g$ are continuous and $f(x_0) \neq g(x_0)$ then $f(x) \neq g(x)$ for all $x$ in some interval around $x_0$.